# Canon MX 870 missing color cartridge I want to print text anyway

Tags: printing, cartridge

Apparently my printer won't let me continue with the printing if I don't have all the cartridges full sitting in it, despite not needing them at the moment. Can I override it somehow?

Comment: Unlikely.  Unfortunately, most printers are this way.  There are some that are not, and not surprisingly, usually advertise it as a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible unless you replace empty cartidges.

Comment: well that's seriously disappointing. thank you

Comment: @pullnointer Yeah. Sadly, these days canon is an *ink* manufacturer, who also happens to sell printers on the side; most printer manufacturers are this way. Laserjets are the way of the future!

Comment: my first printer was a laser one(~300$) that completely died on me 1.5 years after purchase(Samsung :O)